# typeError: Cannot read property 'subCategory' of undefined

Tags: react-native

[image]

> I have array inside object. I got specific object but when I want to 
>       access
>       that specific object value/key I got type error cannot read property of 
>       !!!undefined 'name'

Comment: We can't help you much if you don't show your code.

Comment: https://github.com/tamangsuresh/yellobowboard                                                              problem is from modals folder file line number 29. When I add .name or some key i show undefined.